# how i can write a c code to create a tree using fork()?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, fork

how i can write a c code to create the following process using fork() , and I must Use these functions : wait (0) , getpid() and getppid() to print the id and the parent process id for each process you create.

[this is the the tree that I want to describe it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MI7G3.jpg)

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{

printf("the process id %d" , getpid());

pid_t pid1,pid2,pid3;

pid1=fork();
pid2=fork();
pid3=fork();

if((pid2 == 0)&&(pid3 == 0)) 
  {
     if (pid1 !=0)
   fork();
  }

printf("the process id %d" , getpid());

return 0;

 }
```

Comment: Please describe what you have tried so far.

Comment: What happened when you compiled, linked and tested it?

Comment: Formatting/indentation is hopeless.  Did you just throw the code together?

Comment: Your `pid2=fork();` and `pid3=fork();` statements need to be conditionalized so that only the original process executes them. Otherwise you'll have 8 processes at that point.

Answer (score -2):

`fork()` creates a subthread process.

```
int main ( ) {
    fork();

    printf("Current Process id: %d", getpid());
    printf("Parent Process id: %d", getppid());

    fork();
}
```

This will show an example of how to deal with threads using C in linux.

Answer (score -2):

kindly,check this code please

```
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{

 printf("the process id %d" , getpid());

 pid_t pid1,pid2,pid3;

pid1=fork();

if (pid 1==0)
pid2=fork();
pid3=fork();

if((pid2 == 0)&&(pid3 == 0)) 
{
    if (pid1 !=0)
    fork();
}

 printf("the process id %d" , getpid());

return 0;

}
```